# How to dynamically know if a Google font is serif/sans-serif, and if the font has bold/italic variants

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, google-webfonts

I want to know is if it is possible to dynamically find out if a font is serif/sans-serif (or mono/cursive) or supports bold/italic variants. I'm dynamically building stylesheets so it would be incredibly useful. If not I'll have to create a local dictionary, but I'm hoping to avoid that if possible. Just to be clear, I know you can manually visit the google.com/fonts and get all the relevant information about a font.

EDIT:
The reason I need to know the font details is because when generating css styles it is important to know the appropriate fallback (serif, san-serif, cursive, or monospace). I want to restrict which fonts are selectable for body text, because any font used for the body needs to support bold and italics.

I would like to be able to either pre-generate a dictionary or dynamically check font by font, instead of manually making a dictionary with entries like this:

```
'Aclonica': {string: "'Aclonica', sans-serif", bold: false, italic: false},
```

Comment: [This might help.](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api#Details) It doesn't look like fonts are specifically identified as serif, sans-serif, etc. though.

Comment: @Blazemonger Yeah, it doesn't appear to include that information though it does include a list of the variants and an example of how to compose urls based on that information so thanks for that.

Comment: I'm curious why you need to know? Some google fonts have the word "Serif" in the font name. Or you could build your own list and compare your dynamic font to that list perhaps.

Comment: @NathanielFlick, it's fine to create my own dictionary to compare with locally, which is what I'm doing right now. But that isn't an extensible solution. What if my font list is 100 or 300 fonts in length, that's a lot of work.

Comment: So what is the end result you're after?

Comment: To query an api for that information rather than doing it manually visiting the site and looking and copying information for each font one by one. At the moment I'm using a limited set of 20 fonts but once I add more fonts I wont want to keep updating the dictionary manually

Comment: to avoid an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), what do you need that list *for*? What are you trying to do that you believe requires knowing the font style and weights before loading the fonts?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I edited my question in response to your comment. I need to know the proper css fallback font for any given font. As well as, whether or not the font can be used in situation where text might be italicized or bolded.  I hope that clarifies why I would need a list.

Comment: hm, this feels like overengineering. You generally pick one font and then figure out the fallback stack you need for that font, since the font choice is relatively stable.